# Apache redirection dependent on the given input

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a vpn server which listens to https://sub.domain.com:943 and https://sub.domain.com:943/admin for the admin panel.

I would like to type on my browser (http) sub.domain.com or sub.domain.com/admin and the apache redirections, to redirect me accordingly.

I manage to do the first part my using a simple `Redirect / https://sub.domain.com:943`
But how can I achieve the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was so easy at the end, but I couldnt come up with that on that time.

```
Redirect /admin https://sub.domain.com:943/admin 
Redirect / https://sub.domain.com:943
```